# jQuery not resetting nav element width based upon total li width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I need to dynamically resize my dropdown menu main nav bar so it will resize to accommodate varying lengths of characters in the nav menu item names.  Below is my code so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var wNav = $("#navigation").outerWidth();
            var wLiTotal = 0;

            $("#navigation>ul>li").each(function(){
                wLiTotal += $(this).outerWidth();
                if((wLiTotal > wNav)||(wLiTotal < wNav)){
                 wNav = wLiTotal +3;
             };
          });    
       });
```

The problem is, even though I get the total width of all li's, for some reason it it does not reset wNav to that width and I'm not sure why.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `$("#navigation").width(wNav);` after the each? I think outerWidth() is only a "getter" function.

Comment: Intriguingly, although the docs *claim* that `.outerWidth()` and `.outerHeight()` are only *getters*, you can actually set these by specifying a number instead of a boolean. I haven't experimented on it much, but `outerHeight` certainly works on a large page container with a lot of elements inside it.

Comment: My mistake - its jQuery UI that allows you to use them as setters too. JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tX9u/2/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wNav = $("#navigation").outerWidth();
    var wLiTotal = 0;

    $("#navigation>ul>li").each(function() {
        wLiTotal += $(this).outerWidth();
        if ((wLiTotal > wNav) || (wLiTotal < wNav)) {
            wNav += wLiTotal + 3;  // you've increase wNav with its previous value
        };
    });
    $("#navigation").width(wNav); // set new wNav as new width
});
```

Comment: that did it!  I guess it will all in the placement of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are only calculating outerwidth and not setting it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var wNav = $("#navigation").outerWidth();
            var wLiTotal = 0;

            $("#navigation>ul>li").each(function(){
                wLiTotal += $(this).outerWidth();
                if((wLiTotal > wNav)||(wLiTotal < wNav)){
                 wNav = wLiTotal +3;
             };

            //setting outer width
            $("#navigation").outerWidth(wNav);
          });    
       });
```

using this plugin jquery.dimensions.etc.js
http://bitovi.com/blog/2010/06/set-inner-outer-width-height-with-jquery-dimensions-etc-plugin.html

Comment: try `$("#navigation").width(wNav);` also i cannot understand why the width u want to resize and not the height of dropdown menu

Comment: Shivam: I need to resize the width to accommodate nav item names in different languages i.e. increased characters.

Comment: can you post a demo of what it is doing now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fyV2d/1/ i edited your fiddle, is this you are trying to achieve